# How to add a picklist field in web-to-lead form?

Tags: apex, javascript, ajax

How to add a picklist field to display salesforce account names in  web-to-lead html form.

please suggest any idea to do this

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 2):

You can add a field in Web-To-Lead if its standard/custom field on Lead object. When you create the form you can ad this field as well.

[How do I add another field to my Web-to-Lead Form?](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000005128&language=en_US&type=1)

If its not a field then with Web-To-Lead its not possible to add. You need to write custom code to handle this scenario.